# Probability with Birthdays in a School in Certain Scenarios

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus, statistics

There are 1000 students at a school. Assume there are 365 birthdays in a year.

a. What is the probability that the birthday of a random student is January 1? What is the probability it is not January 1?

b. If you asked two random students their birthdays, what is the probability that neither of will say January 1? If you ask all 1000 students this question, what is the probability that none will say January 1?

c. What is the probability that at least person in the school will say January 1?

d. What is the probability that no one in the school has a birthday tomorrow?

Comment: Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

Assume all dates equally probable.

(a)$\frac{1}{365}$,

(b)  $(\frac{364}{365})^2$, $(\frac{364}{365})^{1000}$

(c) $1-(\frac{364}{365})^{1000}$

(d) $(\frac{364}{365})^{1000}$